# Use very large HTML content in TextView in a fraction of a second

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, epub, pagination

I Use very large HTML content in TextView to create an epub reader application, and i use [PagedTextView](https://github.com/onikx/PagedTextView) library for paginate content.

I have at least 16,000 lines, and for example, when I change the font size, it is applied after 6 seconds.

How can I do this in a fraction of a second?

Comment: Are you loading all the 16000 lines at once or loading them as when the callback for next page comes from PagedTextView?

Comment: Hi @abhiank. I load them all at once. I get all the content from the epub file. I don't think there is any other way.. Have you used this library and is there a better way to load?

Comment: Its not a good idea to load the entire epub file in one shot. This will eventually cause memory problems if big books are loaded. What you need to do it break the book into chunks and load only the page which is visible and maybe two pages ahead and behind. Check out these libs to work with epubs on Android - https://github.com/psiegman/epublib, https://github.com/mertakdut/EpubParser

Comment: In fact, the project's deadline is near. Can these two libraries be right for me?

Comment: The epub parser is a very easy to integrate library. Shouldn't take more than half hour. You need to look into why it's taking 6 seconds. If you dig in I'm sure you'll find that it's taking 6 seconds since the ui thread is trying to render the entire text in the text view in the new size. Since you cannot move that to the background thread, the only option is to break the text itself into chunks so that there isint a huge text to re render

Comment: PagedTextView library split the content into pages, but the text must first be setText completely.

Comment: The library might be showing the content on different pages, but it still have the entire content on memory. You need to reduce the amount of text displayed in the textview.